# Pass data through to fill input fields loaded in ajax Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

on one page i have a button that open an ajax modal using the below code
`<button onclick="showAjaxModalcal('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?modal/popup/add_appointment','09-15-2019');"`

The script for the ajax modal is the below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showAjaxModalcal(url,data)
    {
    // SHOWING AJAX PRELOADER IMAGE
    jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html('<div style="text-align:center;   margin-top:200px;"><img src="assets/images/preloader.gif" style="height:25px;" /></div>');

    // LOADING THE AJAX MODAL
    jQuery('#modal_ajax').modal('show', {backdrop: 'true'});

    // SHOW AJAX RESPONSE ON REQUEST SUCCESS
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {date_timestamp:data},
        success: function(response)

        {
            jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html(response);
            //window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
        }
    });
}

</script>'
```

The modal contains an input filed with the name 
`<input type="text" name="date_timestamp" id="date_timestamp" class="form-control datepicker" data-format="d-m-yyyy" placeholder="">`

What i am trying to achieve is to automatically fill this input field when the ajax modal opens with the value 09-15-2019. The date is not always the same.

The problem is that with the below code i get 
`"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://**************/index.php?modal/popup/add_appointment&date_timestamp=09-15-2019"`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass `date` to modal input when modal show, where as the `date` and modal HTML both are on same page.

**Easiest Solution**

With bootstrap modal event listener and data attribute and let bootstrap do the leg work for you

Modal call button with data attribute `data-date` (date can be dynamic and can be any value)

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-modal="#modal_ajax" data-date="09-15-2019">Whatever</button>
```

Event listener script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal_ajax').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var date = $(e.relatedTarget).data('date');
        $("#date_timestamp").val(date);
    });
});
```

Note: Get rid of `onclick="showAjaxModalcal()` function

**Your Approach**

Remove `url` from modal trigger button

```
<button onclick="showAjaxModalcal('09-15-2019');">whatever</button>
```

And in Script get rid of `Ajax` method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAjaxModalcal(data) {
  alert(data);
  // SHOWING AJAX PRELOADER IMAGE
  $('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html('<div style="text-align:center;   margin-top:200px;"><img src="assets/images/preloader.gif" style="height:25px;" /></div>');
  $('#modal_ajax').modal({
    backdrop: 'true'
  }).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    alert(data);
    $("#date_timestamp").val(data);
  });
}
</script>
```

SideNote: In `Ajax` method, there is no input define to fill up with date

```
success: function(response){
    jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html(response);
    //window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkh2jnkm/)